# How to make Gmail stop replacing the word "Re:" with a translation?

Tags: gmail, languages

I have a friend who has a Sony Xperia X F5121 with Gmail v8.7.15.206199545 on Android 8. Every time he replies to a message in his Gmail app, the app replaces the word "Re:" with "השב:", which is the Hebrew translation for "Re".

When he replies from the Desktop Gmail, then it replies with "Re:", so it only affects him when he uses his phone to reply.

The official support suggests [changing a language setting](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/17091?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid) but his Gmail's settings simply have no language settings. The phone in general is set up to use Hebrew, and he doesn't want to change that. Is there a way to keep it as "Re:" or - if necessary - change only the Gmail app into English without affecting the overall phone?

Comment: If the device is rooted per-app language settings are possible

Comment: @beeshyams how?

Comment: Xposed modules are available, like this [for instance](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.xda-developers.com/app-locale-2-xposed-module-app-language/amp/). I haven't used any of those but search should reveal more

Comment: Without root it's not possible to change language settings differently to system language and modules like these make it possible

Comment: I know other people have by default Gmail in English while the phone is in another language, without any modules or anything. Just by default. How come not for him?